# Wolframalpha - how to get value of function in a specific point?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

For example , given this function  -

$f(x) = x^3-x^2-x-1$

and I want to check it in the point $x=1.6$.

What should I have to write in the command line of [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) in order to get it  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input

```
 evaluate x^3-x^2-x-1 at 1.6
```

seems to work. [Here is the link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate%20x%5E3-x%5E2-x-1%20at%201.6). Here is an image:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

Asking politely:

```
please compute x^3-x^2-x-1 at x=1.6
```

did the work for me.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. I removed the "please" and it did not work :)

Comment: It's rather charming to see such an insistence on manners.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+x%5E3-x%5E2-x-1+at+x+%3D+1.6

However, you could also do a table like this:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%28x%5E3-x%5E2-x-1%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+16%2C+1.6%7D%5D

Answer (score 2):

"evaluate x^3-x^2-x-1 at x=1.6" works for me.